# What is a startup code how it is related to bootloader or bootloader code?

Tags: bootloader, linker, kinetis

I am doing a project on building a bootloader for a kinetis E series controller (MKE02Z64VLD2). My mentor told me to have a thorough knowledge about Startup code and linker files before starting the project. How are they essential for a bootloader code ?

Comment: Useful information here. http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page Good starting point here. http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones (or http://wiki.osdev.org/Ada_Bare_bones if you prefer Ada to C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand how the processor boots, understand the state of the chip on boot, no doubt the boot code is in a flash/rom somewhere.  You have to know where.  Then with that knowledge you have to place the vector table or boot code at the right address per the rules of how the processor boots, which means you need to have complete control over the compiler, assembler, and linker in order to do that.  You are not compiling an application running on linux or windows where the default linker script knows how to place things, this has to be place per the rules of the hardware not the rules of some operating system.